Building Android GKI kernel using "make"
I have kernel source for Qualcomm Snapdragon Kalama SOC. I wan't to build it, but i cannot use bazel as i'm building from Termux environment. The kernel is based on GKI. How to build the GKI kernel and the vendor modules using "make"? Should i merge GKI defconfig and vendor defconfig?
